# Detect the MSS size of TCP session in php

Tags: php, security, tcp

When a HTTP request is made by clients behind VPN, the initial TCP handshake would have a MSS much less than the standard one (1460).  Wonder if it's possible for a php script to get this information and process the request differently.

If possible, some hackers may program it to distinguish requests from security researcher or some security products.

Comment: probably have to go up the food chain from php

Comment: @Dagon, that's the idea. Wonder if it's possible without special privilege.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. But it's very doubtful that some one will do this.

Reason:

1. To access such low level data script must have access to raw TCP data. It is possible only if script listen connections on RAW socket (It must use own implementation of TCP protocol).
2. To be able to open RAW socket script must have root(GNU Linux)/Administrator(windows) privileges.
3. With root privileges there is simpler ways to find how user connect to server.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using raw socket (or equivalently using tcpdump). However this will require some special privilege.   Wonder if there is a generic  way to access such low level info.